# How do you replay the Weasley Boxes lesson level?

Tags: lego-harry-potter-years-5-7

I’m playing *Lego Harry Potter: Years 5–7* — specifically, the first year in the set, *Order of the Phoenix*. I’ve finished year 5, and I’m trying to go through and 100% everything. In particular, I want to go and collect Fred and George’s sweater variants from the Weasley Boxes Lesson segment. However, I can’t figure out how to replay this part, as the board in the Leaky Cauldron isn’t letting me. How do I get to this level?

Answer (score 1):

The Weasley Courtyard is a *Hub location*, not a *Mission story*.  It is located to the right hand side of the entrance to the Great Hall.

Depending on the characters you have access to, and how far through the game you are, you *may* not have the ability to unlock and access it freely yet.